# Unable to convert large files (>1gb) to byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays, alfresco

I need to convert large files (>1gb) to byte array for uploading that file into alfresco CMS repository. I am using `UPLOAD LARGE CONTENT SERVLET` for uploading the large files.

In that program I need to convert file byte array. While executing that I am getting Heap space problem & I am unable to upload that.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: can you post your code?We could suggest some code which could retrieve data part by part. because increasing the heap size to 1 gb is not recomemded

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no problem with the library here. The thing is you are trying to place 1GB of bytes on the memory.
When you start the program, increase the heap size to 1.6G or 2G according to your available memory

```
java -Xmx1600M Main
```

If you are running from eclipse, then right click at project => properties => run time argument and specify `-Xmx2G over there`

Comment: 1.6G - invalid, only integer value is allowed, use 1600M instead

Comment: That is upto him as per code. Either read some bytes from file and keep uploading. Or load all and then do. @Madhuri hasnt put any code here. So we cant help

Comment: Well you can have 2G. I have instances running here with 3G allocated on x86. It is restriction of memory and not architecture type. Though performance can vary